# Error in Installing Unicode::Map module

Tags: perl

I am getting the below error when I am trying to install [Unicode::Map](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwartz/Unicode-Map-0.112/Map.pm) module. I am trying to build this locally using dmake and MinGW for which I downloaded the TAR file from [Metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Map).

```
C:\Users\MG\Downloads\Unicode-Map-0.112.tar\Unicode-Map-0.112>perl Makefile.PL
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Unicode::Map
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

C:\Users\MG\Downloads\Unicode-Map-0.112.tar\Unicode-Map-0.112>dmake
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\CHINSIMP.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\CROATIAN.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\ICELAND.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\ARABIC.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\JAPANESE.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\CENTEURO.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\GUJARATI.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ADOBE\STDENC.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\DEVANAGA.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\CHINTRAD.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\GREEK.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ADOBE\ZDINGBAT.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\GURMUKHI.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ADOBE\SYMBOL.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\DINGBATS.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\CYRILLIC.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\KOREAN.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\HEBREW.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\BIG5.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\JIS-X-0208.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\KSC1001.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\SYMBOL.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\CNS-11643-1986.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\GB12345-80.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\GB2312.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\EUC-KR.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\JIS-X-0212.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\GB2312-80.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\TURKISH.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\THAI.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\EUC-JP.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\ROMANIAN.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\APPLE\ROMAN.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\JIS-X-0201.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\JOHAB.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\ISO646-US.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP737.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-3.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP437.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-9.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-8.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-2.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\SHIFTJIS.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\EASTASIA\KSC5601-1992.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\IBM\IBM038.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-10.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-15.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-4.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-7.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP775.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-14.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-13.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-6.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-5.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\ISO\8859-1.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP862.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP860.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP874.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP857.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\EBCDIC\CP1026.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP865.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\EBCDIC\CP875.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP850.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\MAC\GREEK.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\EBCDIC\CP037.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP863.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\EBCDIC\CP500.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP869.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP866.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\MAC\CYRILLIC.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP852.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP864.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP861.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\DOS\CP855.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP932.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1253.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\MAC\ROMAN.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1254.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\MAC\ICELAND.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP949.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1258.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\MAC\LATIN2.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1251.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1257.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP950.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\NEXT\NEXTSTEP.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1255.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\REGISTRY (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP936.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1252.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1250.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\MAC\TURKISH.map (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\Unicode\Map\MS\WIN\CP1256.map (unchanged)
Running Mkbootstrap for Unicode::Map ()
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 Map.bs
D:\MinGW_4.9.2_Win_O\bin\gcc.exe -c     -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2    -DVERSION=\"0.112\"   -DXS_VERSION=\"0.112\"  "-IC:\Perl\lib\CORE"   Map.c
In file included from Map.xs:21:0:
C:\Perl\lib\CORE/hv_func.h: In function 'S_perl_hash_murmur3':
C:\Perl\lib\CORE/perl.h:1677:31: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #  define INT2PTR(any,d) (any)(PTRV)(d)
                               ^
C:\Perl\lib\CORE/perl.h:1685:19: note: in expansion of macro 'INT2PTR'
 #define PTR2IV(p) INT2PTR(IV,p)
                   ^
C:\Perl\lib\CORE/hv_func.h:391:17: note: in expansion of macro 'PTR2IV'
     STRLEN i = -PTR2IV(ptr) & 3;
                 ^
D:\MinGW_4.9.2_Win_O\bin\dlltool.exe --def Map.def --output-exp dll.exp
D:\MinGW_4.9.2_Win_O\bin\g++.exe -o blib\arch\auto\Unicode\Map\Map.dll -Wl,--base-file -Wl,dll.base -mdll -s -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L"C:\Perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" Map.o   C:\Perl\lib\CORE\libperl520.a -lmoldname -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lcomctl32 dll.exp
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2pv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_block_gimme'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSV'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2mortal'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_die_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_croak_xs_usage'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x25a): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x29b): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSV_type'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2f9): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x31f): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x333): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x37a): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x3ad): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x467): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x47b): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x4a4): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x4b8): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_push'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x4dd): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x539): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newRV'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2mortal'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x57e): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_croak_xs_usage'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x5e8): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x60b): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x632): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x649): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2pv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x791): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x7c2): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x7e1): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x7f2): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x804): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2iv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x816): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x828): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2iv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x835): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x85d): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x86c): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x87e): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x8a3): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x964): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSV'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x985): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_len'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x9b0): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_av_fetch'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xa08): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_hv_common_key_len'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xa80): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2iv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xace): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2mortal'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xb29): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_setsv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xb58): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_catsv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xb67): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xb87): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_croak_xs_usage'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xba3): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xc4f): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2iv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xc98): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSV'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xcab): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_hv_common_key_len'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xce9): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_setsv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xd4c): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_catsv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xd7e): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2mortal'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xdb9): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_croak_xs_usage'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xe64): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xe78): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2iv_flags'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xee4): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xf22): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xf38): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xf67): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xf7b): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0xf82): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_hv_common'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1054): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpvf_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1071): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpvf_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x10fb): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_hv_common_key_len'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1196): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_hv_common_key_len'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x12d0): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1386): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1490): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1744): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1780): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1920): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1b09): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1b62): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSV_type'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1b73): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newRV'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1bc6): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSV_type'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1bd7): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newRV'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1c52): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSVpv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1d99): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1dba): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1e03): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1e24): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1e45): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1e66): more undefined references to `__imp_Perl_warn_nocontext' follow
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1ecd): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1f61): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newSViv'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1f88): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_sv_2mortal'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1fb1): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_croak_xs_usage'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x1fcd): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_get_context'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2027): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2047): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_xs_version_bootcheck'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2050): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_newXS'
Map.o:Map.c:(.text+0x2104): undefined reference to `__imp_Perl_call_list'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\Unicode\Map\Map.dll'
```

> Can somebody help me with what should I do  to remove this error??

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Perl are you using? What Windows OS Version are you on?

You can compile the module, but there are other options available.

If you are using Strawberry Perl, you can simply run the following command to install it.

`cpanm Unicode::Map`

If you are on ActiveState Perl, it would be something like

`ppm Unicode::Map`

Have you tried those?

I have both Strawberry and ActiveState Perl installed. Both at Version 5.24.1 (64 bit) and I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. I could go right up to `dmake install` and it all seems to work fine. So unable to reproduce the issue.

> Editing after OP's update:

Hi....I dont have a copy of ActivePerl 5.20.0, but here are some workarounds-

1) Try installing some other module just to test if it works fine. If it does, try downloading Unicode::Map once again and see. May be there was some file corruption that might have caused it. ( I could be wrong).

2) Use Strawberry perl portable. This is a portable version of strawberry perl that you can download from their site. Note:- You'll have to click on the "All releases: ZIP, Portable, special editions " line that appears under "More Downloads". Download the portable perl version. Follow the readme. Then, install the Unicode::Map so that it gets installed in the same folder. And then copy the whole portable perl folder to the server where you wish to run it.

Here's how you can go about it. I've downloaded the portable version under the Downloads folder. The file name - strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable.zip. After unzipping it, cd to the strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable folder

```
C:\Users\pmu>cd C:\Users\pmu\Downloads\strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable
```

Then run the portableshell.bat file:

```
C:\Users\pmu\Downloads\strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable>portableshell.bat
----------------------------------------------
 Welcome to Strawberry Perl Portable Edition!
 * URL - http://www.strawberryperl.com/
 * see README.TXT for more info
----------------------------------------------
Perl executable: C:\Users\pmu\Downloads\strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable\perl\bin\perl.exe
Perl version   : 5.22.1 / MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
```

From here onwards, <del>till you hit Control+C or some equivalent,</del> till you exit and close the command prompt window, you will be inside this "version" of perl.

Now just cd to the location where you have the untarred file.

```
cd C:\Users\pmu\testthis\Unicode-Map-0.112>
```

Dont worry, you will still be in the "realm" of perl-5.22.1.2.

Now run the makefile command, then the dmake and dmake install commands.

What this will do is, it will install the module inside the "strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable" folder!!

```
C:\Users\ugrankar\Downloads\strawberry-perl-5.22.1.2-32bit-portable\perl\site\lib\Unicode\Map
```

You can then simply copy the folder to the server where you want to run perl from. Just remember to cd to that folder and run the portable.bat again.

Hope this helps.

> Editing the answer for further clarity

Hi Mohit, You dont need to copy anything to the ActivePerl Lib folder at all.

What we want to do is, have a completely separate perl environment on your server for the Strawberry Perl Portable. So your server will have TWO perl environments after you copy the portable perl folder from your laptop on to your server. 
1) The first is the ActiveState Perl. This will be the default one.
2) The Portable Perl. This is the folder that you copy from your laptop onto the server. 
I hope you have unzipped the portable perl folder on your laptop or desktop and ran the commands to install the module inside that portable perl folder. Consider your laptop name is "Mohitlaptop".

After you have installed the module in the portable perl in your laptop, copy the portable perl folder, I mean the entire folder, to your server. Let's say the server name is "Server1". Now what you need to do is, login to server1, open a command prompt, cd to the folder which you have copied from your laptop (Mohitlaptop),

and then run the  `portableshell.bat`command. You do not have to install the module again, because you had installed the module in the portable perl folder on your laptop.

Comment: Hi, I have ActivePerl ver 5.20.0 installed and since I am behind a corporate Firewall I cannot use either of PPM and CPAN command line. So the only option I have is to download the tar file and build the module locally but I am getting error while doing so as you can see in the question posted.

Comment: Hi the module installed in the portable folder. But what do you mean by the last line - Just remember to cd to that folder and run the portable.bat again. I have copied the folder to my ActivePerl lib folder now where should i cd and run portableshell.bat or is it portable.perl which you are referring.

Comment: Also I am still getting the error - Can't locate loadable object for module Unicode::Map in @INC in my script. Please help

Comment: But this way I have to either set this path in @INC or would need to run portableshell.bat everytime before executing the Perl script. Isn't there a way to move this installed module to ActivePerl anyway. That will solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, you will have to run the portableshell.bat every time. You can try to copy paste the folder Unicode that contains the folder Map under it to the ActivePerl and see if it works. It might or might not.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue but I can solve after remove the MinGW path at the Windows environment PATH.